# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.duenndns.ssl.MemorizingTrustManager

Tags: java, android

I am getting no class Def found error. I have added

`<activity android:name="de.duenndns.ssl.MemorizingActivity" />`

in my manifest file. And 'gen' file also contain the package 'de.duenndns.ssl'. I am not able to understand why I am getting this exception. I also googled for this exception but did not get any reasonable answer. Please if anyone already went through this situation help me out from here.

Comment: Already did so many time but issue is still there.

Comment: the error is about the MemorizingTrustManager activity but you have shown the other one make sure have you declared it as well

Comment: Actually same project with same code, was running previously, then I updated android sdk. After that I started getting this error.

Comment: @u_pendra check "MemorizingActivity" available inside de.duenndns.ssl package or not? unless simply add .MemorizingActivity to ur manifest file.

Comment: @Sam I am not getting Android Dependencies Libraries. In my case it is showing as Android private libraries and I am not seeing the package 'de.duenndns.ssl'.

Comment: just import d package